# Locking a PySide (QT) window during query

Tags: python, postgresql, locking, pyside, psycopg2

I have a Q.Widget with thousands of check-boxes that get data from a database and send data back to it once a save button is pressed.

When the save button is clicked, due to the huge amount of data that is being sent to the database, the application goes "not responding" until the transaction is terminated which is a normal behavior since PySide (QT) locks everything until the callback function ends. 
However I find this behavior "unprofessional".

What I want to do is to lock everything (so no modifications can be done to the state of the check-boxes during the query) but without the application going in "no responding" mode.

I have thought of running the query in a separate thread and displaying a Q.MessageBox (which automatically locks the Q.Widget) that is closed only when the query ends but I'm wondering if there is any way to lock the Q.Widget without displaying a message box and displaying a status message at the status bar of the window instead or as a last resort just locking the Q.Widget (no need for a message to be displayed in the status bar) without having it to go in "not responding" mode.

Also, setting all the check-boxes to disabled is not an acceptable option.

System configuration :

- Windows 7 64-bits
- Python 3.3 (installed through windows installer)
- PySide module 1.2.1 (installed through windows installer) Database :
- PostgresSQL 9.3.1 (installed through windows installer(EntrepriseDB))
- psycopg2 module (for communication with the database) (installed
  through windows installer)
- Python editor : PyCharm Community Edition 3.0.2 (installed through windows installer)

Comment: Your requirements seem contradictory. What is the difference between "not responding" and "locked"? And what would be the point of running the query in a separate thread _as well as_ locking the UI with a message box (the latter seems to defeat the purpose of the former)?

Comment: The difference is that I want to make the window locked without having it going "all white" and without Windows displaying "not responding" at the window title and telling the user that the program stopped responding and if he should wait or quit. And this is why I want to run the code in a separate thread, so that the windows doesn't "stop responding" and I can block it myself by other means like by a QMessageMox or as suggested a QProgressDialog or hiding the content...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the time it takes to finish the transaction.

But the way you describe it, I would go for a [`QProgressDialog`](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QProgressDialog.html) - this would give the user the best experience and if you set its modality right, you will lock the UI as well